# Get directory when last folder in path ends in given string (sed in ifelse)

Tags: bash, sed

I am attempting to find multiple files with `.py` extension and grep to see if any of these files contain the string `nn`. Then return only the directory name (uniques), afterwards, if the last folder of the path ends in `nn`, then select this.

For example:

```
find `pwd` -iname '*.py' | xargs grep -l 'nn' | xargs dirname | sort -u | while read files; do if [[ sed 's|[\/](.*)*[\/]||g' == 'nn' ]]; then echo $files; fi; done
```

However, I cannot use `sed` in `if-else` expression, how can I use it for this case?

Comment: As a side note you should paste this into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for syntax help - it can point out common syntax errors like what you're trying to write in your if statement and suggest alternatives.

Comment: @tjm3772 that is helpful, although I have attempted `$(sed 's|[\/](.*)*[\/]||g')  == 'nn'`, but the loop returns nothing and I have checked the output with `sed` and the folder `nn` does exist. It's likely the implementation with `sed` thats not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[ ]]` is not bracket syntax for an `if` statement like in other languages such as C or Java. It's a special command for evaluating a conditional expression. Depending on your intentions you need to either exclude it or use it correctly.

If you're trying to test a command for success or failure just call the command:

```
if command ; then
  :
fi
```

If you want to test the output of the command is equal to some value, you need to use a command substitution:

```
if [[ $( command ) = some_value ]] ; then
  :
fi
```

In your case though, a simple parameter expansion will be easier:

```
# if $files does not contain a trailing slash
if [[ "${files: -2}" = "nn" ]] ; then
  echo "${files}"
fi

# if $files does contain a trailing slash
if [[ "${files: -3}" = "nn/" ]] ; then
  echo "${files%/}"
fi
```

Comment: I did not know of this option `"${files: -2}"`, it's new to me. Your response is very helpful! I also understand the difference between double and single squared brackets. My loop will not work unless I have double. Although, what is the `sed` alternative inside the conditional?

Comment: If you want to use sed, the command would look like: `if [[ $( echo "${files}" | sed 's|a|b|g' ) = 'nn' ]] ; then...`.

Comment: Ah yes that does make sense! This works by including the `-E` flag for `sed` because I am using regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Shell loop and the `[[` is superfluous here, since you use the `sed` anyway. This task could be accomplished by:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -name '*.py' -exec grep -l 'nn' {} + |
    sed -n 's%\(.*nn\)/[^/]*$%\1%p' | sort -u
```

assuming pathnames don't contain a newline character.